# How to get a canvas relative mouse position of a CSS 3D transformed canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, css-transforms

Just for fun I'm trying to draw on 3D transformed canvases. I wrote some code and it kind of works

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;

[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach((canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let count = 0;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const pos = getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, canvas);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 10) / 10, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillRect(pos.x - 1, pos.y - 1, 3, 3);
  });
});

function getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, elem) {
  const pos = convertPointFromPageToNode(elem, e.pageX, e.pageY); 
  
  return {
    x: pos[0],
    y: pos[1],
  };
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}

function convertPointFromPageToNode(elem, pageX, pageY) {
  const mat = m4.inverse(getTransformationMatrix(elem));
  return m4.transformPoint(mat, [pageX, pageY, 0]);
};

function getTransformationMatrix(elem) {
  let matrix = m4.identity();
  let currentElem = elem;

  while (currentElem !== undefined && 
         currentElem !== currentElem.ownerDocument.documentElement) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(currentElem);
    const localMatrix = parseMatrix(style.transform);
    matrix = m4.multiply(localMatrix, matrix);
    currentElem = currentElem.parentElement;
  }

  const w = elem.offsetWidth;
  const h = elem.offsetHeight;
  let i = 4;
  let left = +Infinity;
  let top = +Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    const p = m4.transformPoint(matrix, [w * (i & 1), h * ((i & 2) >> 1), 0]);
    left = Math.min(p[0], left);
    top = Math.min(p[1], top);
  }
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
  document.querySelector('p').textContent =
    `${w}x${h}`;
  matrix =  m4.multiply(m4.translation([
     window.pageXOffset + rect.left - left, 
     window.pageYOffset + rect.top - top,
     0]), matrix);
  return matrix;
}


function parseMatrix(str) {
  if (str.startsWith('matrix3d(')) {
    return str.substring(9, str.length - 1).split(',').map(v => parseFloat(v.trim()));
  } else if (str.startsWith('matrix(')) {
    const m = str.substring(7, str.length - 1).split(',').map(v => parseFloat(v.trim()));
    return [
      m[0], m[1], 0, 0,
      m[2], m[3], 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      m[4], m[5], 0, 1,
    ]
  } else if (str == 'none') {
    return m4.identity();
  }
  throw new Error('unknown format');
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#c1 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c2 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c3 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#c4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: cyan;
  transform: translateX(-250px) rotate(55deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c5 {
  background: magenta;
  transform: translate(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c6 {
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
foo
</p>
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="c3">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c4">
  <div id="c5">
    <div id="c6">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

The code above works. Move the mouse over either of the yellow canvas elements and you'll see it draws correctly.

But, as soon as I add some 3D transform it fails.

Change the CSS for '#c6' to

```
    #c6 {
      background: pink;
      transform: rotate(45deg) rotateX(45deg);  /* changed */
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

and now when I draw over the right yellow canvas things are off.

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;

[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach((canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let count = 0;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const pos = getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, canvas);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 10) / 10, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillRect(pos.x - 1, pos.y - 1, 3, 3);
  });
});

function getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, elem) {
  const pos = convertPointFromPageToNode(elem, e.pageX, e.pageY); 
  
  return {
    x: pos[0],
    y: pos[1],
  };
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}

function convertPointFromPageToNode(elem, pageX, pageY) {
  const mat = m4.inverse(getTransformationMatrix(elem));
  return m4.transformPoint(mat, [pageX, pageY, 0]);
};

function getTransformationMatrix(elem) {
  let matrix = m4.identity();
  let currentElem = elem;

  while (currentElem !== undefined && 
         currentElem !== currentElem.ownerDocument.documentElement) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(currentElem);
    const localMatrix = parseMatrix(style.transform);
    matrix = m4.multiply(localMatrix, matrix);
    currentElem = currentElem.parentElement;
  }

  const w = elem.offsetWidth;
  const h = elem.offsetHeight;
  let i = 4;
  let left = +Infinity;
  let top = +Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    const p = m4.transformPoint(matrix, [w * (i & 1), h * ((i & 2) >> 1), 0]);
    left = Math.min(p[0], left);
    top = Math.min(p[1], top);
  }
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect()
  document.querySelector('p').textContent =
    `${w}x${h}`;
  matrix =  m4.multiply(m4.translation([
     window.pageXOffset + rect.left - left, 
     window.pageYOffset + rect.top - top,
     0]), matrix);
  return matrix;
}


function parseMatrix(str) {
  if (str.startsWith('matrix3d(')) {
    return str.substring(9, str.length - 1).split(',').map(v => parseFloat(v.trim()));
  } else if (str.startsWith('matrix(')) {
    const m = str.substring(7, str.length - 1).split(',').map(v => parseFloat(v.trim()));
    return [
      m[0], m[1], 0, 0,
      m[2], m[3], 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      m[4], m[5], 0, 1,
    ]
  } else if (str == 'none') {
    return m4.identity();
  }
  throw new Error('unknown format');
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#c1 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c2 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c3 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#c4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: cyan;
  transform: translateX(-250px) rotate(55deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c5 {
  background: magenta;
  transform: translate(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c6 {
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg) rotateX(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
foo
</p>
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="c3">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c4">
  <div id="c5">
    <div id="c6">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bad idea mixing CSS transformation and Canvas... go with a proper 3D framework

Comment: You are going to have a lot more fun with a good framework, a lot of the "mundane stuff" is abstracted

Comment: Got it, so you know your way around... I would start reducing the example to something less threatening,  300 lines of code is scary

Comment: Interesting. Didn't had time to truely check in depth what happens (and not sure if I can), but two small observations. IIRC getBoundingClientRect returns a weird thing on 3d transformed elements, that may or may not be related to your issue. And you will want to stop iterating when you find the element's `.offsetParent`, this is not a problem now, but could become one in the future.

Comment: Oh and it's not what the question asks for, but if you want a hack-around, you could place a grid of HTML elements as event listeners over your drawing area. Cwidth Cheight elements, either as 1px x height or 1px x width and then check which are hovered. And actually, did you checked the [DOMPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint) API? Never worked with it myself but might help here.

Comment: Looking at it a bit more, maybe this offsetParent story is actually related. I don't quite get exactly how things should get multiplied between different 3D contexts and 2D ones... Also, I'm not quite sure how your code should handle `transform-origin`. Anyway, [here is the hack-around](https://jsfiddle.net/wvgxaz2p/) I was talking about, if it can help you at least check the expected values

Answer (score 4):

*Note: That's just a complementary answer on what OP already did find by themselves.*

You can actually make this all work by using the [MouseEvent constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent).

You can pass the `clientX` and `clientY` properties of this Event inside the constructor (or `pageX` & `pageY` if you prefer), then dispatching this composed event to your target will set its `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties relative to the target.

Since dispatchEvent does fire the Event synchronously, we can even make a converter:

```js
const init_pos = { x: 50, y: 50};
const relative_pos = {};
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  relative_pos.x = e.offsetX;
  relative_pos.y = e.offsetY;
}, {once: true});

canvas.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
  clientX: init_pos.x,
  clientY: init_pos.y
}));
// synchronously log
console.log(relative_pos);
```

```css
canvas { 
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#c4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: cyan;
  transform: translateX(-250px) rotate(55deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c5 {
  background: magenta;
  transform: translate(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c6 {
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="c4">
  <div id="c5">
    <div id="c6">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, given the example in your own answer, you may want to actually hold a single object that will keep the global Event's position, and to get the relative positions of your canvas at every frame in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop.
However, this setup will obviously traverse your canvases, if you want only the visible face to handle the events, then you'd have to check which one matches `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`, which itself needs your elements to react to pointer-events.

```js
// will hold our last event's position
const pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
// A single global "real" MouseEvent handler
document.body.onmousemove = (e) => {
  pos.x = e.clientX;
  pos.y = e.clientY;
};

canvases.forEach(canvas => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let count = 0;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  function draw(e) {
    // do not fire on real Events
    if (e.cancelable) return;
    
    const x = e.offsetX * canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth;
    const y = e.offsetY * canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
    
    if (x < 0 || x > canvas.width || y < 0 || y > canvas.height) {
      return;
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 10) / 10, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillRect(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);
  }
});

anim();

function anim() {
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);

  // in case we want to paint only on the front element
  const front_elem = single_face.checked && document.elementFromPoint(pos.x, pos.y);

  // at every frame
  canvases.forEach(c => {
    if (!front_elem || c === front_elem) {
      // force a composed event (synchronously, so we are still in rAF callback)
      c.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('mousemove', {
          clientX: pos.x,
          clientY: pos.y
        })
      );
    }
  });
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-duration: 16s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  pointer-events: none; /* no need for mouse events */
}

#single_face:checked+.scene .cube {
  pointer-events: all; /* except if we want to find out who is the front one */
}
label,#single_face {float: right}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( 0deg) rotateY( 0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg);
  }
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.cube__face--front {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: rotateY( 0deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.cube__face--right {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.cube__face--back {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.cube__face--left {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.cube__face--top {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px);
}

.cube__face--bottom {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<label>Draw on a single face</label><input type="checkbox" id="single_face">
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--front"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--back"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--right"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--left"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--top"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!! I wondered if I could dispatch an event but didn't try it. I also didn't know about `document.elementFromPoint`

Comment: @gman And I didn't know evt.offsetX&Y do handle 3D transforms before you post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sigh ... not the definitive answer yet but apparently `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` are supposed to be this value even though [according to MDN they are not standard yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX).

Testing it seems to work in both Chrome and Firefox. Safari is off though in some tests. Also unfortunately offsetX and offsetY do not exist on touch events. They do exist on pointer events but pointer events are not supported by Safari as of 2019/05

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach((canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let count = 0;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const pos = {
      x: e.offsetX * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth,
      y: e.offsetY * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight,
    };
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 10) / 10, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fillRect(pos.x - 1, pos.y - 1, 3, 3);
  });
});

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
#c1 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c2 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c3 {
  margin: 20px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

#c4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: cyan;
  transform: translateX(-250px) rotate(55deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c5 {
  background: magenta;
  transform: translate(50px);
  display: inline-block;
}
#c6 {
  background: pink;
  transform: rotate(45deg) rotateX(45deg);  /* changed */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
foo
</p>
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
    <div id="c3">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c4">
  <div id="c5">
    <div id="c6">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately we still have the issue that sometimes we want a canvas relative position outside of an event. In the example below we'd like to keep drawing under the mouse pointer even when the pointer is not moving.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach((canvas) => {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width  = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  let count = 0;

  function draw(e, radius = 1) {
    const pos = {
      x: e.offsetX * ctx.canvas.width / ctx.canvas.clientWidth,
      y: e.offsetY * ctx.canvas.height / ctx.canvas.clientHeight,
    };
    document.querySelector('#debug').textContent = count;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 100) / 100, 1, 0.5);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (window.PointerEvent) {
    canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', (e) => {
      draw(e, Math.max(Math.max(e.width, e.height) / 2, 1));
    });
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', preventDefault, {passive: false});
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, {passive: false});
  } else {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', preventDefault);
  }
});

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation-duration: 16s;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  0deg) rotateY(  0deg); }
  to   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(360deg) rotateY(720deg); }
}

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.cube__face--front  { background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--right  { background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--back   { background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--left   { background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2); transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--top    { background: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--bottom { background: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2); transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--front"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--back"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--right"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--left"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--top"></canvas>
    <canvas class="cube__face cube__face--bottom"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```