# Raycaster doesn't work when the phone is in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can select objects on PC.
But i run it on phone, it's not work!

**PC screenshots:**
[image]
**Phone screenshots:**
[image]

**NOTE**: I rotated the canvas 90 degrees on the phone by the CSS（I guess it's because of this operation, but I don't know why）:

```
transform-origin: left top;
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

export class PickupManager {

    raycaster: THREE.Raycaster;

    camera: THREE.Camera;

    scene: THREE.Scene;

    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;

    constructor(camera: THREE.Camera, scene: THREE.Scene, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {

        this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

        this.camera = camera;

        this.scene = scene;

        this.canvas = canvas;

        this.addEventListener();
    }

    pickedObject: THREE.Object3D | any;

     ljj1: THREE.Object3D = null;
     ljj2: THREE.Object3D = null;
     ljj3: THREE.Object3D = null;
     ljj4: THREE.Object3D = null;
     ljj5: THREE.Object3D = null;

    pick = (normalizedPosition: THREE.Vector2) => {

        this.ljj1 = this.ljj1 || this.scene.getObjectByName("LJJ1");
        this.ljj2 = this.ljj2 || this.scene.getObjectByName("LJJ2");
        this.ljj3 = this.ljj3 || this.scene.getObjectByName("LJJ3");
        this.ljj4 = this.ljj4 || this.scene.getObjectByName("LJJ4");
        this.ljj5 = this.ljj5 || this.scene.getObjectByName("64mmB016");

        // 通过摄像机和鼠标位置更新射线
        this.raycaster.setFromCamera(normalizedPosition, this.camera);

        // 计算物体和射线的焦点
        const objects = [this.ljj1, this.ljj2, this.ljj3,this.ljj4, this.ljj5];
        const intersectedObjects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(objects,true);

        if (intersectedObjects.length > 0) {    
            this.pickedObject = intersectedObjects[0];

            const obj:THREE.Object3D = this.pickedObject.object;
            //output name of selected object
            console.log(obj.name );

        } else {

            console.log("Not found!")
        }
    }

    getCanvasRelativePosition = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {

        const rect: DOMRect = this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        const position: THREE.Vector2 = new THREE.Vector2();

        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {

            position.x = event.clientX ;
            position.y = event.clientY;

        }

        else if (event instanceof TouchEvent) {

            const touch: Touch = event.changedTouches[0];

            position.x = touch.clientX - rect.left;
            position.y = touch.clientY - rect.top;

        }

        else {
            throw "Incorrect event, needs MouseEvent or TouchEvent";
        }

        return position;
    }

    getPickPoint = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {

        const canvasPosition = this.getCanvasRelativePosition(event);

        const pickPoint:THREE.Vector2 = new THREE.Vector2();

        // 将鼠标位置归一化为设备坐标。x 和 y 方向的取值范围是 (-1 to +1)
        pickPoint.x = (canvasPosition.x / window.innerWidth ) *  2 - 1;
        pickPoint.y = (canvasPosition.y / window.innerHeight) * -2 + 1;

        return pickPoint;

    }

    addEventListener = () => {

        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);

        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onTouchStart, false);

    }

    onMouseDown = (event: MouseEvent) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        this.pick(this.getPickPoint(event));

    }

    onTouchStart = (event: TouchEvent) => {

        event.preventDefault();

        this.pick(this.getPickPoint(event));

    }

}
```

I want get the `ljj1`,`ljj2`,`ljj3`,`ljj4`,`ljj5` object, i can get it on PC, but i can't get it on phone.

Comment: Have you tested that rotation on your PC first? With the transform origin at the top-left, you might be rotating the element almost completely off the page.

Comment: @Andrea I use the css: margin-left: 100%; move canvas , and exchange window size and canvas size by the code: canvas.style.width =`${window.innerHeight}`;  canvas.style.height = `${window.innerWidth}`; so we can see the scene

Comment: this is online demo: https://wlczmsc.com/U3D/app.html

Answer (score 0):

If you rotated the canvas using CSS then the way you compute mouse/touch coordinates won't work.

For handing CSS transformed elements you need some relatively complicated code

For mouse coordinates you can use `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`

For touch coordinates you need to generate synthetic events that pass the event position back into the browser so that it will generate `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` for you.

See [How to get a canvas relative mouse position of a CSS 3D transformed canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654650/how-to-get-a-canvas-relative-mouse-position-of-a-css-3d-transformed-canvas)

Also see [this example](http://greggman.github.io/doodles/test/3d-css-and-offsetXY/3d-css-and-offsetXY-working.html) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/greggman/c28bfbe50f6a27e53626a6860cf168a3)